# Checkbox validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, alert, attr

I need help in the selection checkbox on the form. I would like to display an alert  as a form checkbox is unchecked (only). My code:

```
<form action="index.php?page=contact&amp;send=ok" method="POST" id="form">
[...]
<label for="message">Checkbox:</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">           
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="testcheck()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function testcheck()
{
    if (jQuery("#checkbox").prop("checked"))
        alert("first button checked");
    else
        alert("none checked");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2uhv/

Comment: @Asad If you're not sure what the problem is, consider your addition of `jQuery("#submit").click(testcheck);`

Comment: @MBJ It works even with the inline handler, so I still don't see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jwmsu/

Comment: I wish that the form is not sent when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code should work:

```
function testcheck()
{
    if (!jQuery("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        alert("none checked");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return testcheck()" />
```

`return false` will stop execution of default action (form submition)

Comment: well almost, I would like to block form before sending unchecked checkbox. Unchecked checkbox sends the form.

Answer (score 5):

FAngel is right, but I would also do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="testcheck" />
```

And:

```
$("#testcheck").on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        alert("first button checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("none checked");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/hU4UY/

Comment: The problem with that js is that the submit will occur regardless. You need to return false and/or use `preventDefault`.

Comment: @Asad The OP made no mention of needing such functionality.

Comment: I know, just trying to mind read what the OP wants here

Answer (score 2):

Dude, can be three methods using jQuery.

They are: .prop(), .is() and .attr().

As example, i will demonstrate these codes:

```
function testcheck()
{
    if (jQuery("#checkbox").prop("checked")){
        alert("first button checked");
}
    else{
        alert("none checked");
}
}


function testcheck()
{
    if (jQuery("#checkbox").is(":checked")){
        alert("first button checked");}
    else{
        alert("none checked");
}


function testcheck()
    {
        if (jQuery("#checkbox").attr("checked")=="checked"){
            alert("first button checked");}
        else{
            alert("none checked");}
    }
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Bye and Good Evening

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function testcheck(e)
{
    if (jQuery("#checkbox").prop("checked")){
        alert("first button checked");
    }
    else{
        alert("none checked");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

jQuery("#submit").click(testcheck);
```

I'm guessing the problem you were having was that the submit went ahead anyway.